# JPA findBy...IgnoreCase and PostgreSQL indexing

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have following question about `findByUsernameIgnoreCase` lookup and indexing.
For example i have DB column `username` (unique index) in `users` table and i want case insensitive lookup.
For now all the records are in UPPERCASE.

The question is `findByUsernameIgnoreCase(...)` will use the indexing or not?

In specification the outcome of IgnoreCase is `where UPPER(username)=UPPER(?1)` which confuses me in order of index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For method `findBy...IgnoreCase("someName")` Spring Data JPA generate a like this SQL:

```
select ... from users u where upper(u.username) = upper('someName')
```

So in case of using it with index you should create an 'upper(username)' index, like this:

```
create index index_users_username_upper on users (upper(username));
```

Query plan example:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on parents p  (cost=83.17..8791.50 rows=5000 width=346) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: (upper(username) ~~ 'SOMENAME'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_users_username_upper  (cost=0.00..81.92 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (upper(name) = 'SOMENAME'::text)
Planning time: 0.207 ms
Execution time: 0.051 ms
```

I think that storing `username` in uppercase is not necessarily in that case...

---

You can always create your own query method that will match your conditions, for example:

```
@Query("select u from User u where upper(u.username) = ?1")
List<User> findByUsernameIgnoreCase(string name);
```

In this case you can use simple index by `username`.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question about indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Recent update,

In **`Spring-Boot 3`** and it's respective version of **`spring-data-jpa`**, the implementation from `Spring` has changed and uses always **`lower()`** function to implement the **`ignoreCase`**.

The **`upper()`** is not used for **`ignoreCase`** any more.

So in case you already had some `index` in database defined and based on `upper` transformation of the column as the accepted answer here points to, you have to modify the database index to use `lower` function if you want to continue to have the benefits of index in `spring-boot 3` in scope of **`ignoreCase`**.